# Unexpected parameter value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

I am having trouble understanding what's wrong here. I get a list of events from a database and I'm trying to create a custom list to display them, with a callback onclick method. I get the right values, I display them correctly but the onClick method gets the value of the last item ID, instead of it's own.

So if I click in any of the items in the list my alert says

`show itinerary for event: 10`

instead of the correct ID (I have 10 events now)

This is how I handle the items I got from the db:

```
function gotEvents(transaction, result) {
             var eventList;
             var myDbElements = $('#myDbElements');            
             var params = {
                items:result.rows.length,
                hasImage:false,
                content:[]
             }
                   if (result != null && result.rows != null) {

                       for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                          var row = result.rows.item(i);
                          var rowText = row["Name"] + '<br/>' +  row["Start"].slice(0,9);                    


                          var rowId = row["id"];
                          var contentItems = {
                            text: rowText,
                            onClick: function(){ showEventItinerary(rowId) }

                          }
                           params.content.push(contentItems);                      
                          }
                          for (var j=0; j<result.rows.length;j++){
                            PrecAppPersistence.debugObject(params.content[i]);
                          }
                          eventList = PrecAppComponents.myList(params,$('#eventsList'));
                   }
                PrecApp.I_SCROLL.refresh();   
               }


            function showEventItinerary(event_ID) {
                alert("show itinerary for event:"+event_ID);
            }
```

And here is how I create my list:

```
function List() {

var self;
var items;
var firstRun = true;

this.initialize = function(params,cont) {
    self = this;
    var container = cont;

    var items;
    container.empty();
    opt = {
            items:0,
            content:[], // array with the content. Default is = {text:text,icon:imageURL,onClick: function(){}}  itemId // not sure if we need this yet. supposed to be a manual ID for the item. EX: id taken from the db.                                         
            width: 300,
            hasImage: false, //set true if you want to show an images
            margin:10, //margin between items               


    }
    for (i in params) opt[i] = params[i];

    items = opt.items;
    container.width(opt.width);

    for (i=0;i<items;i++){

        itemToAdd = '<div class="listItem" id="listItem'+i+'">'; //add IDS to add click                        
        if (opt.hasImage) {
            itemToAdd += "<img src=" + opt.content[i].image + " />";
        }               
        itemToAdd += "<p>" + opt.content[i].text + "</p>";
        itemToAdd += "<div class='clearFix'></div>";
        itemToAdd += '</div>';      
        container.append(itemToAdd); //original #scroller might change?     

        listItem = $('#listItem'+i);    
        listItem.css('margin',opt.margin + 'px 0');
        listItem.on('click',opt.content[i].onClick);            

    }


}}
```

I am logging my variables, my rowId has the correct ID. And the onClick log shows the following for all items:

`onClick:function (){ showEventItinerary(rowId )}` (I'm not sure if this is correct, shouldn't it show the value of rowID instead of the variable rowID?)

Did i miss something here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a closure, as your index i gets updated with the loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {(function(index){
// use index instead of i inside your loop
...
// end closure
})(i);
// end loop
}
```

The self invoked function will be executed with index=i. i is part of the loop and its value will change, while each function within the loop will keep its own index.

Comment: I'm new to javascript so, for the sake of clarity, this is a self invoked function that has I as parameter?

Answer (score 1):

There is no block level scope for `rowID` either use an array to store each item in loop or use a `closure` to create separate scope for each iteration.

Check [the infamous loop problem](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/)